# What should my MVC Core app's Program class look like for hosting in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

At the moment, the `Program` class is default, as created by the MVC Application project template, and looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

I know that I should also have a `UseIISIntegration` call somewhere in there, and that `Kestrel` should be somehow involved, but I know nothing more than that.

Could somebody please give me an example on what the content of the `Program` class should look in order than my MVC app is properly configured for hosting on IIS. The MS Docs [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1) topic only has this less than meager example:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        ...
```

Comment: In situations like this I just deploy it and google any resulting error message

Comment: Did you read the MS Docs? The fifth bullet point starts with `When running behind IIS, enables IIS integration.`...

Comment: `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` already takes care of Kestrel ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L153)) and IIS  ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L206)) for you.

Comment: As some one already mentioned in the comments and also in the docs linked, That `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` method does all the heavy lifting of configuring IIS integration setting up Kestrel. That default should be enough to get hosted on IIS. It replaces a lot of what was done manually in asp.net-core-1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.Net Core 1.x as you are accustom to when enabling the IISIntegration components you would have done

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    ...
```

as both `UseKestrel` and `UseIISIntegration` are required.

In the more recent version, Asp.Net Core 2.x, that has been combined inside the [`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.0) method

> The following defaults are applied to the returned WebHostBuilder: use Kestrel as the web server, set the ContentRootPath to the result of GetCurrentDirectory(), load IConfiguration from 'appsettings.json' and 'appsettings.[EnvironmentName].json', load IConfiguration from User Secrets when EnvironmentName is 'Development' using the entry assembly, load IConfiguration from environment variables, configures the ILoggerFactory to log to the console and debug output, enables IIS integration, enables the ability for frameworks to bind their options to their default configuration sections, and adds the developer exception page when EnvironmentName is 'Development'

To quote the documentation again

> A typical *Program.cs* calls `CreateDefaultBuilder` to begin setting up a host. `CreateDefaultBuilder` configures *Kestrel* as the web server and enables IIS integration by configuring the base path and port for the ASP.NET Core Module

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    ...

    In Asp.Net Core 1.x as you are accustom to when enabling the IISIntegration components you would have done

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    ...
```

Using the `WebHostBuilder` is still a supported approach with ASP.NET Core 2.x.

Reference [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1)

For more information on hosting in Asp.Net Core

Reference [Hosting in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore1x)

Comment: Thanks. I have read and re-read the topic `Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS`, but the only mention of the `BuildWebHost` method is as with your last code example, ending with `...`, kind of just letting the novice reader to guess what code is supposed to go where the `...` is.

Comment: @ProfK did you click on the tab for core 1.x to see the earlier examples?

Comment: @ProfK check hosting topic for the other options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x because the docs in the answer focus on IIS they only show that but the bulk of the info on hosting is in the link i just provided